# Software configuration questions: Am I too strict about what's on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I've seen a few questions like these:

- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946107/unable-to-access-webui-for-nagios*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943813/my-emails-mark-as-spam-in-gmail-email-configure-perfactly*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846462/how-to-modify-the-squashfs-in-centoss-livecd*

I used to flag them as off-topic, as I feel they belong to Super User/Server Fault, but most of my flags ended up as *disputed*. Am I overlooking an obvious direct relation to programming / software development here?

Comment: 'Flags' are direct signals to moderators, who have to decide on a case-by-case what to do with it. With just a little more reputation, you can *vote to close* for exactly that same reason, and then it's just a case of finding 4 like-minded close voters. (I don't know why low rep users *need* to use flags for this.)

Comment: @RadLexus: *should be closed* and *duplicate* flags do **not** reach moderators. Instead, they route posts into a review queue. All other types of flags though, as you said, *do* go through to a moderator (and sometimes into a queue as well, depending on the type of flag, and state (vote count etc.) of the post).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The first two are 100% off-topic. They have nothing to do with programming and do not belong here. Flagging for closure is correct.

The third might be programming-related, but it too deserves to be closed - it's talking about a problem without bothering to detail the exact steps taken to trigger it, or listing the actual errors received.

Your flagging is fine. The reviewers that are disputing the flags (which doesn't count against you - only diamond-mod *declines* do) are wrong.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a penalty when moderator declines a flag?

Comment: @AlonEitan If it happens too often to you in a time-window, you temporarily cannot flag anything anymore.

Comment: So I guess people explicitly commenting "I'm voting to close this because (...)" do so not to educate the author, but rather to give a clue to reviewers who would otherwise skim the question and think "it's clear and all the information is in place, looks OK". Maybe I should do that too.

Comment: @rafalmp I think these comments are auto-generated by 3k users when they use a custom close reason *(source: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/224130 - Free-form reasons will be presented as comments, but the close dialogue will refer the reader to the comments for more info)*. But I'm not saying you shouldn't post these by hand.

Comment: @rafalmp Those messages (especially custom ones) serve both to clue in other reviewers/voters and to help educate the OP on why their question is off-topic.